# How to order iteration columns for agile kanban board?

Tags: xml, tfs, agile

I'm setting up a process template and want to order the columns within an iteration. Where can I alter this order?

I have setup my STATES and TRANSITIONS however when displayed on the Web, my ordering is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to order iteration columns for agile kanban board?

According to the document [On-premises XML process customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=azure-devops-2019&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops), we could [Set default columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/process-configuration-xml-element?view=azure-devops-2019#set-default-columns).

So, to order iteration columns for agile kanban board, you can try to following steps:

1. Export the Agile process template:
   [image]
2. Unzip the `Agile.zip`, and open the file `ProcessConfiguration.xml` under the folder `WorkItem Tracking\Process`. Then we change the order of the columns, like change `Title` `State` To `State` `Title`:

   The XML of default columns under the **User Story** should be:

   ```
   <RequirementBacklog category="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" pluralName="Stories" singularName="User Story" workItemCountLimit="1000">
     <States>
       ...
     </States>
     <Columns>
       <Column refname="System.WorkItemType" width="100" />
       <Column refname="System.Title" width="400" />
       <Column refname="System.State" width="100" />
       ...
     </Columns>
   ```

   Then I changed the order of `Title` and `State`:

   ```
   <RequirementBacklog category="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" pluralName="Stories" singularName="User Story" workItemCountLimit="1000">
     <States>
       ...
     </States>
    <Columns>
       <Column refname="System.WorkItemType" width="100" />
       <Column refname="System.State" width="100" />
       <Column refname="System.Title" width="400" /> 
       ...
     </Columns>
   ```
3. Change the name and version type(*Randomly modify a few digits*) in the `ProcessTemplate.xml` file in the root of the folder:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ProcessTemplate>
     <metadata>
       <name>AgileTestByLeo</name>
       <description>This template is flexible and will work great for most teams using Agile planning methods, including those practicing Scrum.</description>
       <version type="ADCC42AB-9882-485E-A3ED-7678F01F56BD" major="16" minor="1" />
       <plugins>
         ...
       </plugins>
     </metadata>
   ```
4. Zip that folder and import this `.zip` file to the process, create a new project with this custom process:
   [image]

Now, the order of the columns has been modified correctly.

Note:The `TRANSITION` element is used to define a transition for each valid progression and regression from one state to another.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much this is the solution to the question. I did realise through your answer that I should have explained further into the question that I was looking particularly at the columns on the board of the iteration, however this solution pointed me in the right direction as to the ordering of those columns as well. Most helpful, thank you.